# Split response from server

Tags: android, string, split, tokenize

I have a response coming from the server which is like this:

```
{"success":"89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494|2"}
```

I want to split this response.How can i achieve it?

Comment: how you want it to be look like after splitting?

Comment: i want "success" ,"89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494" and "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; 
//{"success":"89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494|2"}

String SuccessTokens = (String) jsonObject.get("success");  
// 89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494|2

StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer (SuccessTokens, "|");
if (st1.hasMoreTokens())
{
   String token1 = st1.nextToken(); //89F00539-25EA-E311-853B-000C29762494
   String token2 = st1.nextToken(); // 2
}
```

You would have to combine JSON parsing and String Splitting via stringTokenizer

Answer (score 1):

use the method: [split().](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

ex:

```
String string = "004-034556";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use parse the JSON Object.. Kindly refer how to Parse JSON Objects;